# How to add extra Widgets in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, widget

In my current WordPress theme, i have some 5 widgets. 
I tried with plugins available on internet but that not solved my problem.
I want to use more widgets in my theme in single sidebar.
How can i add more widgets in WP theme?
Thanks

Comment: do you want to add more widgets or more sidebars ?

Comment: just drag n drop the widgets from left to your sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Most widgets give you a shortcode to put into one of the pages that wil be `echoed` out through the `the_content();` function.

So if you would like to process those shortcodes in the PHP to make them in custom places would probably be your best bet.

You can do that like this:

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>
```

[Here is the reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)